# i need to do something if an id exist inside a div, and if not, do something else

Tags: javascript, html

i have the next code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
   <iframe id="inside"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to do something if id="inside" exist, and if not, do something else. Notice that id="inside" is inside another div, and this div is in a container div with class="container"

I need to identify if exist id="inside" (inside ) no matter how much divs are between  and  (because i only want to know and do something if this id="inside" exist or not.

Can anyone help me?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally people will want you to at least post some code in which you have tried to develop the answer on your own.

Comment: So select the element? `document.getElementById("inside")` if it does not exist, you will not find it....

Answer (score 2):

you can do the following:

```
if(document.getElementById("inside")) {
    //do something since id exists
}
else{
    //do something else since id does not exist
}
```

It checks if en element with the id exists, and if so, allows you to execute some code, otherwise executes the other code block.

Answer (score 0):

you can use querySelector for this. Only if #inside exists as children from .container the result is `true`

```js
const inside = document.querySelector('.container #inside');

if(inside) {
  console.log('inside exists');
} else {
  console.log('no inside');
}
```